# Java POI Exporting to excel with empty row is ignored when importing it

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have java program for Export/Import excel files (.xls) using Apache POI lib (I'm using HSSF prefix classes for old excel .xls files).

My excel format is:
Row 1 : Title 
Row 2 : Empty 
Row 3 : Table with header and content

Lets say my table has 5 rows including the header, thus, 7 rows in total.
I'm exporting the data to a excel file, the file size 6k.
Without changing nothing in the file I'm importing it and while debugging the import I realized that I number of rows is 6! which means it ignores the empty row for some reason which I don't understand.

Next scenario, I export the file open it with MS Excel save it, file size is changed to 24k.
I perform import and it works, total size of rows is 7 again.
The export and start of import code is below:

```
public static TempFile createExcelFile(String sheetTitle, String title, String headerSummary, List<String> header, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> data)
{
    TempFile result = new TempFile(FileKeyFactory.getFileKey(ExcelReporter.class).getFullPathKey());
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet spreadSheet;
    DataFormat format = null;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    // Get a DataFormat object and use it to create a CellStyle object
    // with the following format set for the cells @. The @ or ampersand
    // sets the format so that the cell will hold text.
    format = wb.createDataFormat();

    if (sheetTitle != null)
    {
        spreadSheet = wb.createSheet(sheetTitle);
    }
    else
    {
        spreadSheet = wb.createSheet();
    }

    if (title != null)
    {
        // Title
        HSSFFont titleFont = wb.createFont();
        titleFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
        titleFont.setItalic(true);
        HSSFRow titleRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        HSSFCell cell = titleRow.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(title);
        cell.getCellStyle().setFont(titleFont);
        spreadSheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 100));
    }
    else
    {
        spreadSheet = wb.createSheet();
    }

    HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));

    if (headerSummary != null)
    {
        HSSFFont headerFont = wb.createFont();
        headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 9);
        headerFont.setItalic(false);

        HSSFCellStyle headerCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        headerCellStyle.setWrapText(true);

        HSSFRow headerRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        HSSFCell headerCell = headerRow.createCell(0);

        headerCell.setCellValue(headerSummary);
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        //increase row height to accommodate two lines of text
        headerRow.setHeightInPoints((9 * spreadSheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));

        //adjust column width to fit the content
        spreadSheet.autoSizeColumn((short) 1);
        spreadSheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 100));
    }


    /*
     * Data table header
     */
    HSSFRow dateRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    HSSFCreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
    HSSFCell cell = dateRow.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Created: " + DateParser.toString(calendar, DateParser.MONTH_WORD_DATE_FORMAT));
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    HSSFFont headerTableFont = wb.createFont();
    headerTableFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
    headerTableFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());

    HSSFCellStyle tableHeaderStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    tableHeaderStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
    tableHeaderStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    tableHeaderStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    tableHeaderStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    tableHeaderStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
    tableHeaderStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index);
    tableHeaderStyle.setFont(headerTableFont);
    tableHeaderStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    HSSFRow tableHeaderRowRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);

    for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
    {
        HSSFCell ipHeaderCell = tableHeaderRowRow.createCell(i);
        ipHeaderCell.setCellStyle(tableHeaderStyle);
        ipHeaderCell.setCellValue(header.get(i));
        spreadSheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

    /*
     * ********************** DATA *******************
     */
    HSSFCellStyle dataCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    dataCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
    dataCellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    dataCellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    dataCellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    dataCellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

    //spreadSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
    for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> row : data)
    {
        HSSFRow currentRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
        {
            HSSFCell dataCell = currentRow.createCell(i);
            dataCell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);
            dataCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

            String celVal = row.get(header.get(i));
            dataCell.setCellValue(celVal);
        }
    }

    // Resize columns automatically.
    for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
    {
        spreadSheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(i, style);
        spreadSheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

    FileOutputStream resultOutStream = null;
    try
    {
        resultOutStream = new FileOutputStream(result);
        wb.write(resultOutStream);
        resultOutStream.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.ERROR("File path: " + result.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + result.getName(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException("File path: " + result.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + result.getName(), e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (resultOutStream != null)
            {
                resultOutStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignore)
        {

        }
    }

    return result;
}

public void import()
{
    ...
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    rows.next(); // skip title
    rows.next(); // skip empty row
    List<String> header = getLine((HSSFRow) rows.next());
    ...
}

private List<String> getLine(HSSFRow row)
{
    List<String> header = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while(cellIterator.hasNext())
    {
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)cellIterator.next();
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        header.add(cell.toString());
    }

    return header;
}
```

Any idea why after exporting and importing it again the empty row is ignored while calling sheet.rowIterator()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. From the [Javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#rowIterator%28%29):

> Returns an iterator of the PHYSICAL rows. Meaning the 3rd element may not be the third row if say for instance the second row is undefined.

If you look at the [Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), you'll see that described in more detail, along with instructions on how to force the iteration over all rows in a range if that's what you really want. Your code will want to be something like (taken from the Apache POI docs)

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   if (r == null) {
      // Handle empty row
      continue;
   }

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting although I would prefer not to limit the sheet to hard-coded min/max rows.

Comment: I checked your code. I don't need the min/max because I know that I am always starting from zero and I just need the last row and it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I never experienced this issue but I'm using sheet.getRow(row) instead of rowIterator(). I guess it may be a bug in the rowIterator implementation in POI (which you should report to them).

So can you please try to change your code from:

```
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
rows.next(); // skip title
rows.next(); // skip empty row
List<String> header = getLine((HSSFRow) rows.next());
```

To:

```
int row = 0;
++row;  // skip title;
++row;  // skip empty row
List<String> header = getLine((HSSFRow)sheet.getRow(row)); ++row;
```

Hope it works.

Note: you also should use 'Workbook', 'Sheet' and 'Row' instead of 'HSSFWorkbook', 'HSSFSheet' and 'HSSFRow'. That would save you some typing and your code would be ready in case you need some day to process some XLSX file !

Comment: It's not a bug, it's very much the expected and documented behaviour of the row iterator